# Multiple Divs On One Line With Even Spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a Slider with a few images. Inside this slider, i have a div called "sb-bolas", and inside this div, i created new div's where i have a circle, and inside this circle i want to insert some text.
But i need to create more then 1 circle and i want to every circle have the same space between them.

How can i do this?

HTML

```
<div class="sb-bolas">
   <div class="bolas-grad">something</div>
   <div class="bolas-grad">something</div>
   <div class="bolas-grad">something</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sb-bolas {
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    background: #CBBFAE;
    background: rgba(190,176,155, 0.4);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);   
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms;
    -o-transition: all 200ms;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
.bolas-grad {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007EFF, #09f);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

****UPDATE*****

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JsQR.jpg)

Comment: The issue is the **position:absolute**, they will always be positioned absolutely within the confines of the nearest **position:relative** parent element. You should position them relative and float left with equal margins.

Comment: the first div doesnt need to be absolute? i just added position relative to my sub divs, with float left..but didnt work out

Comment: can you please set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dwhite.me please, take a look

Comment: As my previous comment, can you please set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Either of the two answers should work based on your code. Please make a jsfiddle so that we can see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eUMLw/9/ this isnt showing the circles.

Comment: This isn't showing anything in Firefox. Are you sure you have included all the relevant markup?

Comment: Yes. I have added all divs and CSS things i have in my php files

Comment: I see a blank fiddle unless I remove your slideshow. You must be using an external script that we don't have access to.

Comment: now it's working! it was a wordpress tag that was blocking. thank you alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `float:left;` and `margin`

Keep in mind, using **float** will remove any **absolute** positioning you may have established with its parent element. To further help clarify what exactly you need to do, we don't have enough context with the rest of your **HTML**. Please provide more detailed code if you want a more detailed answer.

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/qwA32/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" style="background:#C00;">

    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="background:#0C0;">

    </div>

    <div class="slide" style="background:#00C;">

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slideshow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

div.slide {
    float:left; //        <------- Here
    margin-right:50px; // <------- Here

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #007EFF, #09f);
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/qwA32/2/

Comment: How does that not work? It does exactly what you've described at the top... did you view the fiddle...?

Comment: now it's working! it was a wordpress tag that was blocking. thank you alot!

Answer (score 0):

Add property

`display:inline-block;`

to the class `.bolas-grad`  to have the circles in the same row.

To have even spaces add `margin` to the class `.bolas-grad`